# Download and install Samba on CentOS manually

Tags: centos, installation, samba, yum

I need to install Samba on a CentOS machine that has no internet connection, and to which I can only access remotely through an intermediary Windows machine. I have no experience with CentOS so I asked about how to set up Samba, and I was advised to use `yum` to download and install it automatically. However, since the machine has no internet access, yum doesn't seem to work. I imagine I will need to download Samba manually and then install it myself on the machine.

I would need step by step instructions on how to do this. In particular:

1. Where do I get the Samba setup package from?
2. Once I get the Samba package on to the machine, how do I install it?

Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RPMs you want are: samba, samba-client and samba-common.  If you want a web interface to samba, you will want the samba-swat RPM.  You can find these at any number of Centos repo sites and download them via ftp, wget or whatever.  Then you can create a local repository on your Centos box (see man createrepo) and install them using yum.

Comment: Does anybody just "rpm -I package1.rpm package2.rpm ..." anymore?

Comment: Don't think so.